# install Nuance voices on a web hosting server

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm creating a text-to-speech application. it's an ASP.NET application that makes use of the System.Speech namespace to convert some text to .wav audio format.

the thing is that I want to be able to install multiple Nuance voices on the server to make use of them in my application.

is there any website hosting provider (like godaddy.com) that can allow a web application owner to install programs on their system ? is there another way to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [dedicated server](http://help.godaddy.com/article/127) from many ISP's including [GoDaddy.com](http://help.godaddy.com/article/199). This will basically be your own server, you can install anything you want. However, this will be pricey, you can look into a [virtual dedicated server](https://www.godaddy.com/gdshop/hosting/virtual.asp?isc=goaz2001cq&app%5Fhdr=&display=virtual&ci=13779), which is cheaper and should allow you to install whatever applications you need.